# input field value in session variable in php

Tags: php, javascript, session, variables

Can we use input type value in session variable without any form submitting

like there is an input field

 now i want to save above input field value in a $_session['anyname']; when there is no form  in page.

Comment: How are you supposed to have an input field without a form?

Comment: From the sounds of it, you are asking for AJAX.  There are many great sources where you can (and should) read up on the subject.  Here's an intro from w3c schools: http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/ajax_intro.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in set.php:

```
<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION['value'] = $_POST['value'];

?>
```

in the *non-form form* page.php:

```
<?php session_start() ?>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setVal()
{
  var val = jQuery('#value').val()
  alert('Setting the value to "' + val + '"')
  jQuery.post('set.php', {value: val})
  alert('Finished setting the value')
}
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout('setVal()', 3000)
})
</head>
<body>

<form>
<input id="value" type="text" name="value" value="value">
<input id="value2" type="text" name="value2" value="value2">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

this will record the value (after a 3 second delay)

test it in test.php:

```
<?php

session_start();
echo '<pre>';
echo htmlentities(var_export($_SESSION, true));
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

now it's in your session with no form submit

Comment: He specifically requested there to be no form submission required.

Comment: there is no form submit, but you need a <form> element if you want to catch events, even if you're not submitting

Comment: how to do that?? please suggest me

Comment: now how to show that session variable value in set.php page or how do i know that the value is really coming or not

Comment: not changing any value from that input box, bcoz value in input box also coming from another javascript, and i m doing all these stuff on backend, i means not any user interference( it shoud done automaticaaly)

Comment: which event? i want that it calculate automatically and show me the data of that input field

Comment: you can call the `setVal()` function to store the value, in an event or when the doc loads.

Comment: Thank you jspcal........................
U saved my life
Thanx a ton..n keep in touch.....
u r really great teacher

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your best bet is to set up a separate PHP script that is called upon via Javascript with the input field information in the query string (`ajax.php?key=value`) and stores that information to a `$_SESSION` variable.

That PHP would probably look something like this:

```
session_start();
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value)
   $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
```

Comment: how to call javascript on a input box? i m doing all thing between the login page and dashboard page( just after login) i mean where i doing all database stuffs

Comment: let me know actaully what i m doing? i m using a google map to find distance from given input field from all distance that is in my database, and if distance is desired then who onlt those places name  on dashboard , so i have to do all this stuff in beetween login and main page , do u have any other solution?? please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery and PHP

The HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="autosend" />
```

The JavaScript

```
$(function(){
   $('#autosend').blur(function(){
       $.post('receiver.php',{fieldval:$(this).val()},function(response){
          alert(response);
       });
   })
})
```

The PHP

```
$_SESSION["somename"] = $_POST["fieldval"];
echo $_SESSION["somename"];
```

Now, whenever input field looses focus, the session variable will be updated with the current value.

Comment: Dear i dont want to blue or any event on that input field on that page( eg x.php), bcoz value from that input field is coming through another javascript and that value i have to use on next page , bcoz the page(x.php) where that value is coming will not showm anywhere.

actauuly i m signing in on a.php and after signing in i goes to b.php , but meanwhile a.php and b.php there is 'x.php' where i m doing database stuffs and  i need that input field value on that page (x.php) want to use at 'b.php'